# Modifying an Object versus modifying a copy of that object

Tags: c++, object

I've tried to SSCE my problem as best possible, but it involves mulitple objects defined in C++. They are simple, though - I think its best if I share my code before explaining further:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Cell {
        bool visited;
        Cell():visited(false) {}
        void setVisited(bool val) {visited = val;}
        bool beenVisited() {return visited;}
};
struct Vector2D
{
        int size;
        std::vector<Cell> myVector;
        Vector2D(int n): size(n), myVector(n*n) {}
        Cell& getAt(int x, int y) {return myVector[((x * size) +y)];}
};

int main()
{
    Vector2D vec = Vector2D(1);
    Cell cell= vec.getAt(0,0);

    cell.setVisited(true);
    cell = vec.getAt(0,0);
    if (cell.beenVisited() == false)
        std::cout << "Why is this not true like I set it a moment ago?\n";
}
```

I apologize sincerely for all of this, but it is needed to make the point. As you can see, I getAt() what I think to be Cell object, set its visited instance data to true, and then switch off to another cell. Why, then, when i come back to that same cell, find that the visited value is false instead of true?! It's like it isn't registering my private data change!

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: No.  [_this_](http://ideone.com/2fSjR) is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  27 lines of code, has the same issues as your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cell cell= vec.getAt(0,1);
```

copy of object.
Use

```
Cell& cell = vec.getAt(0, 1);
```

or simply

```
vec.getAt(0, 1).setVisited(true);
```

**EDIT.**

This code should works.

```
using namespace bob;
Vector2D vec = Vector2D(5);
vec.setAt(0,0, Cell(0,0));
vec.setAt(0,1, Cell(0,1));
vec.setAt(0,2, Cell(0,2));
Cell& cell= vec.getAt(0,1);

cell.setVisited(true);
Cell cell1 = vec.getAt(0,2);
cell1 = vec.getAt(0,1);
if (cell1.beenVisited() == false)
{
    std::cout << "Why is this not true like I set it a moment ago?" << std::endl;
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/53634eda052a07885d4e6c062a0fd302

Comment: I'd like to use the & operator... but when I try that it still prints the output/shows the behavior above. Is there some other trick to using the operator? (Keeping in mind that getAT returns a Cell&).

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade: In `Cell&`, `&` is not an operator (operators are functions).  It means the `Cell` is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

ForEveR's answer is correct -- you need to store the value returned by getAt() in a reference variable, rather than copying it into a value variable.

You might consider explicitly declaring that the "Cell" class should never be copied, which will help you catch this type of error sooner.  This can be done by declaring a private copy constructor (with no body); or if you're using boost, then it can be done by inheriting from the base class "boost::noncopyable" ([docs for noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable)).